# Docker starting error: failed to check bridge interface existence: no buffer space available

Tags: docker

I've got a error in docker starting process

> Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge"
> network: failed to check bridge interface existence: no buffer space
> available

below is the error tracking:

```
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.243123905Z] Starting up                                  
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.244395780Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.244560010Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.244707290Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.244885240Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.246091201Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.246243462Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.246383162Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.246511172Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.252291567Z] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.253495388Z] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2021-06-11T04:11:19.284746098Z] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: failed to check bridge interface existence: no buffer space available
```

I found nothing by using google and internet, maybe nobody met this error before?

Comment: Im using centos 7.3 now and run docker in a vmware

Comment: Follow [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18113) thread. They have provided a solution by deleting network-db file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, finally I found the solution, that is ipv6, yes

when u enabled ipv6 in ur vmware linux that will occur this error if u didnt configure the ipv6 settings of docker @ /etc/docker/daemon.json and didnt set the ipv6 cidr

there are two places that must be configured with ipv6 options, ipv.disable=false in
/boot/grub2/grub.cfg and ipv6 switch in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-xxx

done